# SharePoint Online Global Navigation Levels

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm using Term Store for use with Managed Metadata. I have four levels of navigation. On a modern page the navigation shows all levels from the term store, but on a classic page (which there are quite of few of) only shows 3 levels. Note the differences between the two below. Can someone clarify - is this just the way it works when using a classic page in SPO? It's not some sort of configuration setting I'm missing right?  Thanks.

Modern page

```
IT
  Enterprise Systems
    BI/DBA
      SharePoint
      Site360
```

Classic page

```
IT
  Enterprise Systems
    BI/DBA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, classic pages supports term navigation upto 2 levels only so definitely   you are not missing any configurations here.

The only possible way I know to allow Navigation for more than 2 levels is customizing the Master Page by following the below steps:

- In SharePoint site, find out which master your site is using. In the site, go to **Site Settings**, then choose master page under **look and feel** section. Check which master page is selected in each drop down.
- Open **SharePoint designer**, navigate to **Master Pages** and select the used master page from step 1.
- Click edit file and find the **maximumdynamicdisplaylevels** value and change the number to as per your requirement.
- Save the file, refresh the browser and see if you get other levels of terms in navigation.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect for using on my old classic pages. Works great.